# If $f$ is even then $f'$ is odd, if $f$ is odd then $f'$ is even. Why can't we apply this result for $f(x)=x^4$, $x \geq 0$, $f(x)=-x^4$, $x<0$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

This question is based on problem 28b from Spivak's Calculus, chapter 9, Derivatives.

If a function $f$ is even, then $f'$ is odd:

$$f(x)=f(-x)$$

$$f'(x)=-f'(-x)$$

where we use the fact that if $f(x)=cg(x)$ then $f'(x)=cg'(x)$.

If a function $f$ is odd, then $f'$ is even:

$$f(x)=-f(-x)$$

$$f'(x)=-1(-1)f'(-x)=f'(-x)$$

where we use the fact that $f'(cx)=cf'(cx)$

Consider the function $f(x)=x^4$, for $x\geq0$ and $f(x)=-x^4$, for $x<0$.

If $x > 0$ then $f(x)=x^4$. Then,

$$f'(x)=4x^3$$
$$f''(x)=12x^2$$
$$f'''(x)=24x$$
$$f^{(4)}(x)=24$$
$$f^{(k)}(x)=0,\ k>4$$

Now let's consider $x<0$. $f(x)=-x^4$. This is simple to differentiate, and we get the same results as before but with a minus sign.

Can we reach the same results thinking in terms of odd and even functions?

$f(x)=-x^4$ is an even function. Therefore

$$x<0 \implies -x>0$$

$$f'(x)=-f'(-x)=-f'(|x|)=-4x^3$$

$f'(x)$ is thus odd, remembering that we are considering $x<0$. Thus $f''$ is even:

$$f''(x)=f''(-x)=f''(|x|)=12x^2$$

This latter result is incorrect.

I believe the issue here is that when we say that $f''(x)=f''(-x)$, for $x<0$ this particular $f''$ is now different from the $f''$ that we obtained when $x>0$.

Is this the reason why these calculations don't work?

Comment: $|x|^{4}=x^{4}$ for all $x$, positive or negative.

Comment: Question has been amended with the correct function.

Comment: If  $f(x)=x^4$ when $x\ge 0$ and if $f(x)=-x^4$ when $x<0,$ then $f$ is odd and $f'(x)=3|x^3|$ is even.

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x)=\begin{cases} f_1(x)=x^4, x \geq 0 \\ f_2(x)=-x^4, x \leq 0 \end{cases}$$

This function is odd.

Hence $f'(x)$ is even:

For $x>0$:

$$f'(x)=f'(-x)$$
$$4x^3=-4(-x)^3=4x^3$$

$f''(x)$ is odd:

$$f''(x)=-f''(-x)$$
$$12x^2=-(-12(-x)^2)=12x^2$$

For $x<0$:

$$f'(x)=f'(-x)$$
$$-4x^3=4(-x)^3=-4x^3$$

$$f''(x)=-f''(-x)$$
$$-12x^2=-(12(-x)^2)=-12x^2$$

In the calculations of the original question, the mistake was to take the fact that $f_1(x)$ and $f_2(x)$ are each even and then conclude things about the odd/even status of the derivative of $f_1'$ and $f_2'$, but then mixing the definitions of odd/even of these functions with the definition of the original function $f$.

$f_1(x)$ and $f_2(x)$ are each even, even though $f(x)$ is odd.

When we consider $x<0$, we can't try to say:

$$f_1'(x)=-f_2(-x)$$

because this is the same as saying that $f'(x)$ is odd. But it is even.